# Not able to write into excel using setCellData in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, selenium

I am writing the below code to write "Pass" in the column "Results" of my excel sheet "TestCase_A1".

```
public class Updateresult_data {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Xls_Reader x = new Xls_Reader(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\src\\com\\plumslice\\xls\\A Suite.xlsx");
        setresult(x, "TestCase_A1", 2, "Pass");
    }

    public static void setresult(Xls_Reader xls, String testname, int rowNum, String result)
    {
        xls.setCellData(testname, "Results", rowNum, result);
    }
}
```

`Xls_Reader` is a method which reads xlsx files, which is working fine in other programs

Comment: Please share seCellData method

Answer (score 0):

The error is resolved now, I deleted and again installed all related jar files in my eclipse.